# How do you add a session variable into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently tying to add the session variable `$username` into a table in my database. I currently have two tables one for users and a second for articles. Both tables have the value `username`. I am just really confused.

```
$user = new User();

if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
}


$user = DB::getInstance()->insert('article', array(
        'username' => ($username),
        'article' => 'Example',
        'time_posted' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

    ));

?>
```

Comment: $_SESSION['username']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access a variable stored in the $_SESSION array you need to use this syntax `$_SESSION['myvariable']`.

So you should use

```
'username' => $_SESSION['username']
```

instead of

```
'username' => ($username)
```

Comment: Hmmm I did try this, I got the error - Undefined index: username

Comment: so this could mean you haven't any `username` key declared in the $_SESSION array

Comment: Are you sure you're doing a session_start() in the PHP?

Comment: Yeah definitely doing a session_start(); as I've included a require 'core/init.php'; at the top of the page. Although I don't have a function for storing the username? Should I create one? I thought the username would automatically be stored as a variable?

Comment: Hmmm You can simply store a value inside by doing `$_SESSION['username'] = 'theusername'` anywhere in your code as you can read from here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: @ilpaijin: okay, that did insert a value into the database but how would I go about creating the session username variable?

Comment: I think I'm lost. I suppose you still stored somewhere the $_SESSION['username']; So your question was 'How to add that session variable into the db'...

Comment: I actually managed to solve this simply with:

    'username' => ($user->data()->username)

Was easier than I originally thought.

But thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

heFirst, you have to start a session in your page for you to be able to use session based info transfer along your site.
If you are sure you make the session initiations correctly in every page you use sessions than you need to assign the username value to the session with a syntax like this: `$_SESSION['username']="some username";// or from some database result.`
If you do this after all make  `var_dump` to the session to see that your session is carrying to info you need. if you see your username in the results than that means you correctly assigned the value to your session and it is carrying it.
and the last in your column name array, call to the username as this: `'username'=>$_SESSION['username']`
that should do it.